# How do I bundle maven submodule jars into one jar file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I have `maven` module `inventory` that looks like

```
<groupId>com.org.my_services</groupId>
<artifactId>inventory</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Inventory</name>

<modules>
    <module>persistence</module>
    <module>business</module>
    <module>services</module>
    <!--<module>integration</module>-->
    <module>converter</module>
</modules>
```

**what I want**

I want to create a single jar `inventory.jar`, which contains jar files for

```
persistence.jar
business.jar
services.jar
```

I am a maven newbie and don't really know how that is possible

I am using `Maven 3`

**Update**

I want this to be a `Library` that can be used by other teams

Comment: What sort of output is that `inventory.jar` supposed to be? Library, standalone executable, `war`, Spring Boot?

Comment: It has to be a Library

Comment: Make another module called *bundle*, which will have other modules as dependencies and use maven-assembly-plugin to make a single jar.